# Increasing RAM usage - R in ubuntu

Tags: r, ram

I am currently running a code. My CPU is 100% but my RAM is only 20%. I was told that having more RAM can speed up things. But how can I make the system use more RAM?

Comment: Which code are you running?

Comment: R Code, but I using Rscript to run it from CMD.

Comment: It can speed things up *if* more RAM is necessary.  You may not need RAM and may just need faster processing power.  It's hard to say without more details.

Comment: I was told that RAM is important than CPU (dont know if its true). Wouldnt having my RAM work at higher than 20% make things a bit faster? 

@Dason, what kind of details would you require?

Comment: If this code needed more RAM, your use would be higher than 20%. So your bottleneck here is CPU, not RAM. Anyway, I asked exactly what code are you running? Copy it here, though I think the answer is pretty obvious.

Answer (score 1):

As it was pointed out in comments that the optimal amount of RAM and computational power depends on the problem you are solving.

As an example let's consider iterative increment (which loads CPU) and matrix operations (which loads RAM).

For the reference, when it execute nothing execept of the background services, my R session consumes CPU: ~0% , RAM: ~54 Mb (Sony Yoga 260, Windows 10, however the same principles are applicable for Ubuntu):

[image]

Let's generate ten million normally distributed random numbers (one-by-one, using `while`-loop):

```
i <- 0
while(i < 1e7) {
  rnorm(1) 
  i <- i + 1
}
```

it consumes moderate amount of RAM however loads the processor to the full (my CPU is multicore so there is not 100%, but ~ 30%).
[image]

If you run some memory demanding algorithm (like big matrices multiplication) the amount of memory is vital as if you do not have enough RAM you'll need to access HDD and it's a way slower. See below the example of Cartesian product - all the combinations of vector elements -  of two vectors with 10 000 elements:

```
z <- expand.grid(seq(1e4), seq(1e4))
```

[image: cross product]

As a conclusion to use your CPU and RAM more effectively you need to:

1. Use vectorized computations (change `for`-loops into apply-family functions as well as migrate from scalars to vectors). R is very efficient with vector \ matrix handling.
2. Use [parallel computations](https://cran.r-project.org/web/views/HighPerformanceComputing.html) to utilize all your processor cores.